# Can you jump while wearing Juggernaut armor?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I was playing some Spec Ops Missions with a friend the other night, and one of them put us both inside suits of Juggernaut armor.  I've only briefly used Juggernaut armor before, but I noticed I was unable to jump while wearing it in the mission.  I was wondering if Juggernaut armor in multiplayer behaves the same way or not.

If I get Juggernaut armor during a multiplayer match (either of the two killstreak options), will I be able to jump?  Or am I stuck on the ground for the duration of the armor's lifespan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found detailed information about the juggernaut strike-chain on [this](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernaut_Recon) and [this](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernaut_%28Assault_Strike_Chain%29) entry on a call-of-duty wiki. basically:

- you can't jump
- you can't go prone
- you can't pick up weapons
- you're moving very slow (65% speed)

this is consistent with my personal experience as far a i remember (i'm at work now and havn't played for about 9 hours or so, maybe i remember wrong)

Comment: You can't prone either. Edited