# Is Support Juggernaut only defensive?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Modern warfare 3, is the Juggernaut in support pointstreak package only for defensive, IE you can't shoot or attack?  I got it briefly but that's what it looked like it only was for, but wanted to verify....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you *can* attack, but obviously less effectively than the Assault Juggernaut. The Riot Shield has a melee attack (bashing), and you also get a USP .45 pistol as a secondary weapon.

The shield is mostly useful for defending (say, a control point), but if you get a couple of team mates to follow you, you can also provide an nigh-invincible distraction and cover for an offensive front.

Comment: I believe it's dual wielded pistols.  You also can't go prone, jump (you can mantle, however) or pick up weapons off the ground.  You can do some pretty serious damage as a support Juggernaut.  It's certainly not a defensive-only unlock.

Comment: @agent86 Unless that was changed recently, I don't think it's dual pistols. Also, I'm pretty sure the Riot Shield prevents you from going prone, not the Juggernaut armor.

Comment: Yep, I retract that part of my statement, I could've sworn it was dual, but it's just one.  I'm pretty sure no Juggernaut can go prone, unless [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42502/can-you-jump-while-wearing-juggernaut-armor) is wrong.

Comment: @agent86 Well, the source that answer is citing says something different now (the exact opposite in fact), which is partly why citing a wiki is silly. In single player and Spec Ops, Juggernaut actually does prevent you from going prone.

Comment: I can't seem to shoot anything, how do you get the pistol?

Answer (score 0):

The Support Juggernaut also has it's own portable radar that goes with it wherever it goes. This is something the Assault Juggernaut does not have. The Support variant is aimed at helping the team, hence why it has a riot shield and a portable radar equipped. The pistol isn't as useful but it can get one or two enemies out of the way at a time. If you and a number of your team mates have Assassin Pro equipped, the Support Juggernaut can become a big threat to the enemy team, because even if your team gets EMP'd or a Counter UAV from the enemy team is put up in the air you can still see enemies not using Assassin because you never lose your radar.